# innerHTML = Date() working in fiddle, but not in Chrome or IE

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, jsfiddle

So I decided to just randomly make an updating time and date element using JavaScript and HTML. The code is below:

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="timer.js"></script>
</head>
   <body>
    <span id="time"></span>
   </body>
</html>
```

JavaScript(timer.js)

```
var e = document.getElementById("time");
window.onload = setInterval(
    function () { 
       e.innerHTML = Date();
},
    1000);
```

It works in this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Agony/sQ9D9/), but does not work when I load the HTML with Google Chrome and especially not with IE. Does anyone know why that is? This is more of a question of curiosity rather than a coding issue. Thank you for the feedback!

Comment: As a sidenote Date() really returns a date object, and you should convert it to a string even if most browsers do that for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`setInterval` does not return a function. It returns an ID you can use to cancel it later. The `getElementById` is also outside of it, so that will just return `null` because the element isn't loaded yet when it's trying to get it. Fixed code:

```
window.onload = function() {
    var e = document.getElementById("time");
    setInterval(function() { 
       e.innerHTML = Date();
    }, 1000);
}
```

Comment: Good eye, and that's why it works in the fiddle where the onload handler is selected, changing it to no-wrap in head breaks it.

Comment: TMYK, thank you. This worked. I was not aware that `setInterval` returned an ID. Thank you :)